# Can't lauch SPA proxy for net6 + react app

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, .net-6.0

I'm creating a new project based on ASP.NET CORE Web Application + React template. Then I configure ClientApp for my needs - innstead of CRA I use my own webpack.config.js. Frontend works fine, it launches as expected when I run it with `npm start`. But backend won't launch. The problem comes from SPA Proxy which is not working properly. When I start the app I get the following message: `SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page`. Meanwhile the frontend page opens correctly, but without proxy server the app basically doesn't run. Any ideas what I am missing?

The content of my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.65.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

The content of .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:5206</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="6.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPubliFsh Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPubliFsh>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpackDevServerPort = 8083;
const proxyTarget = "http://localhost:5206";

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.tsx',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: './dist',
        proxy: {
            '*': {
                target: proxyTarget
            }
        },
        port: webpackDevServerPort
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:45536",
      "sslPort": 44368
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Project1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5206",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the issue?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your `ClientApp` directory.
2. Run the following command in terminal:

> npm i spa-proxy

---

If the solution above fails, try this:

1. Open your `ClientApp` directory.
2. Run the following command in terminal:

> npm update

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this issue come when we take project from another person or download project from internet and try to run our project then we have issue to run the app.
You can fix this by opening .env.development.local in the root folder and make sure that you have correct computer user name path in certificate path.
[image: spa react app not running]

Answer (score 0):

you should remove these files and then run your app:

```
     SSL_CRT_FILE=C:\Users\NameofYourUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\NameOfYourProject.pem
    SSL_KEY_FILE=C:\Users\NameofYourUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\NameOfYourProject.key
```