# Launching the SPA proxy... This page will automatically redirect to https://localhost:44426 when the SPA proxy is ready. .net6 and react

Tags: reactjs, .net-6.0

rigth now i´m creating a little crud in react and .net6 to learn new skill, i getting little issues, the principal is this Launching the SPA proxy...
This page will automatically redirect to https://localhost:44426 when the SPA proxy is ready. when i start the project tha page automatticaly show that then a console open and show this

> crud2@0.1.0 prestart
> node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react

> crud2@0.1.0 start
> rimraf ./build && react-scripts start

then the console close and open again and again and i dont know how solved please help :)

i try to solve restart de pc if some of the ports was in using while the application was running but doesnt work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The post helped me .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72786176/cant-lauch-spa-proxy-for-net6-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when running the Angular implementation of https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture They have a React implementation, so I guess that the solution applies the same (and it may be similar).

I was able to fix this problem after running `npm run install` in the `ClientApp` level, where the Angular `package.json` file is located. This is, I installed the required dependencies for the Angular project (keep in mind I had to delete at some point the `node_modules` folder and reinstall everything a second time).

[image]

Be sure you're executing their commands in the correct order.

In the case of this project, you should run `dotnet watch run` in the `Web` layer for executing their SPA Angular App. And that should be enough (this worked for me too).

But you could also, as I did, run the server side code and the front end code separately, just to be sure. In the case of this project:

1. Server side: Run the `Web` layer hitting F5 in Visual Studio 2022
2. Client side: Run the Angular project from its root level, using NPM (for this specific project, it was `npm run start:windows`).